# Mris rets does not allow search by ListingKey

Tags: rets, phrets

I have a list of ListingKeys that are updated since 2015-01-01

Then Id like to fetch all the metadata and values based on that field (listingKey). I'm expecting to search by arrays of listingKeys.

So my DMQL2 query is

```
(Listingkey=10026515129,10026515170,10039422998,10039789519,10039789557,10039789596,10262631304,10383785355,10383787516,10389025847)
```

And the response from MRIS is

```
    [PHRETS\Exceptions\RETSException]                                                                    
 'Listingkey' is not a valid search item for SearchType = 'Property' and Class = 'MRIS Residential'.
```

I'm surprised that 'Listingkey' is not searchable, its unlikely because its unique and a primary key, if we want to sync our database we could easily do this by ListingKey.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using www.retsmd.com to verify that the 2nd parameter in your Search request is a valid class name under the Property resource.  Unless the server is misreporting something, I'd doubt that "MRIS Residential" is the value you want for the 2nd parameter.

If you could paste the Search line you're using completely, that would help.  I regularly pull listings by primary key from that server so I know the software is capable of it.